# Conditionally static_assert if function is called constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr, static-assert

I know that there is a proposal for the constexpr() operator, but this isn't implemented in gcc/clang yet. I also know that there is a implmentation using some tricks like machine-code editing:

http://saadahmad.ca/detecting-evaluation-context-inside-constexpr-functions/

I wonder if there is a somewhat restricted solution to this:

```
struct F {
    constexpr F(int v) {
         if constexpr(constexpr()) {
             static_assert(v > 0);
         }
         else {
             assert(v > 0);
         }
    }
};

// ...

constexpr F f{0}; // should trigger a compile-time error
```

I know the static_assert couldn't be used in such a way, but this is only to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your particular case you can just leave assert - it will prevent compiling when the condition is wrong since the assert handler is non-constexpr:

```
#include <cassert>

struct F {
    constexpr F(int v) {
         assert(v >0);
    }
};

// ...

constexpr F f1{0}; // doesn't compile in debug
constexpr F f2{1}; // compiles
```

However this won't trigger the compile-time error in release. It can be solved by making your own assert and adding call to some non-constepxr function:

```
#include <cassert>

// some non-constexpr function
void AssertConditionFailed()
{
}

#define ASSERT_WIH_COMPILE_TIME_CHECK(...) \
    assert(__VA_ARGS__); \
    if (!(__VA_ARGS__)) \
    { \
        AssertConditionFailed(); \
    }\

struct F {
    constexpr F(int v) {
         ASSERT_WIH_COMPILE_TIME_CHECK(v >0);
    }
};

// ...

constexpr F f1{0}; // doesn't compile
constexpr F f2{1}; // compiles
```

Comment: I spent all day trying to figure out how to get a compile-time assert to work that I could tie to a constexpr, with no luck until I found this. This is hands down, the best option I have seen so far. All I had to do was define a function, whose name was the "error" message that I wanted the compiler to show, and then call the function in the constexpr, and it works like a charm. Nice an elegant. I only wish C++ didn't need this kind of hack.

Answer (score 2):

Not in such a direct way, because `static_assert` will simply not be allowed there, and similarly trying to use `v` as a template argument will fail so no use of `enable_if` type solution.

For the purposes of errors, if a constexpr results in an exception, you will get a compile error.

You could use a macro such as `assert` (allowed since C++14) allowing it to be optimised out in release builds and keeping your original debug runtime behaviour.

```
constexpr int foo(int v)
{
    if (v < 0) throw std::invalid_argument("invalid v");
    return v * 2;
}

int main() {
    int a = -1;
    int a2 = foo(a); // Not evaluated at compile time
    constexpr int b = foo(2);
    constexpr int c = foo(-1); // ERROR
}
```